# A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

Tags: variables, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, kpi

I am trying to create KPI and for that i try to create a variable

i have this formula

```
Total_Sales_Variable = 
IF ( 
    VALUES (BillingDocument_Header[Billing Doc. currency_WAK] ) = "USD",
    139.2,
    1
) * 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM (BillingDocument_Item[Sales Amount_NEWR]),
    FILTER ( 
        'Invoice_Calender',
        'Invoice_Calender'[Fiscal_Year] = 2016 &&
       'Invoice_Calender'[Fiscal_Year]  = 2017
    ),
    FILTER ( 
        'BillingDocument_Header',
        'BillingDocument_Header'[Bill Type_FKRT] <> "Z2" &&
        'BillingDocument_Header'[Bill Type_FKRT] <> "Z2"
    )
)
```

when i add this shows an error

MdxScript(Model) (8, 5) Calculation error in measure 'Invoice_Calender'[Total_Sales_Variable]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

and i am trying of achieve if Billing Doc. currency_WAk is USD then i want to sum of this field Sales Amount_NEWR against filters Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'} and [Billing Type_FKART] ={'ZG2','ZL2'}

this is what i want to achieve in power bi i want to convert this into dax expression power bi
qlik sense expression

```
    if([Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = 'USD',
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR])*139.2,
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR]))
```

any help ?

**UPDATE ATTACHED FILE**

kindly check pbix file with data and tables

https://www.dropbox.com/s/flondhallo08j98/test4.pbix?dl=0

Comment: [Edit] your question to show a sample of your source data, and the expected output from the measure.

Comment: hi .this is impossible for me to put source data because of huge size.. and when i use code which i mentioned in question this shows nothing but an error

Comment: A **sample** of data, to show the structure and some representative rows...

Comment: can i show tables and their fields ?

Comment: i know what is mean by sample data. i said this is not possible because of large number of rows..

Comment: It seems likely that you need some sort of iteration (probably a SUMX) to perform the `IF` statement for each row of _some_ table. With no understanding of your source data structure though, it's impossible to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: ok here is the link of my data.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tr3epqtetf36hfl/abc.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Your measure refers to multiple tables... Which table is that? What are you actually trying to achieve with your measure? Please, read [ask], and clarify your actual question. It's very difficult to help you, without all the relevant information.

Comment: and here is the link of tables .. https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3hsphvttc2c473/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: check my updated question @Olly

Comment: It's still really not clear what you actually want. Are you trying to multiply USD values by 139.2? Or only return a sum of values where currency is USD? What is the relationship between the tables, and how does this relate to the sample data you provided? The measure itself should be relatively simple, but your definition needs to be clearer.

Comment: hello... its simple i think i only want  to sum those if currency is USD  with filters which i mentioned  and in one condition i want to multiply by 139.2 and on the other condition not..

Comment: if you have know how about qilk sense expression then kindly check update question where i mentioned qlik sense expression ..

Comment: @Olly check please updated  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: Now we finally have clarity on your table structure and relationships, and understand your required measure!

```
Total Sales Variable = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUMX ( 
        VALUES ( test_billing_doc_header[Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] ),
        IF ( 
            test_billing_doc_header[Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = "USD",
            139.2,
            1
        ) * SUM ( test_biilingg_doc_item[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR] )
    ),
    Invoice_Calender[Fiscal_Year] = 2016 || Invoice_Calender[Fiscal_Year] = 2017, 
    test_billing_doc_header[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZG2" && test_billing_doc_header[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZL2"
)
```

PBIX file: https://pwrbi.com/so_55914086-3/

Comment: hi in last line..  BillingDocument[Billing Type_FKART] = "ZG2" || BillingDocument[Billing Type_FKART] = "ZL2 i want to operate as "not equal to " sign .. when i replace = to <> this shows an error

Comment: hi i already did that one as i menitoned in comment but this shows an error. and when i replace <> to = this then no error but when i replace = to  <> then this shows an error .... and i want <> operator not = in last condition ..

Comment: Edited answer again, to make the filter criteria clearer.

Comment: check table structure please which i edit in question

Comment: I'm doing ALL the work, here... How about you mock up a PBIX file with the table structure and relationships you're working with, and some sample data?

Comment: kindky check update question .. i attached pbi file.. in that file i use = instead of <> so this shows an error .. i used  your previous code kindly check and please modify ... @Olly

Comment: have you checked.. kindly check if you not

Comment: I have completely updated my answer. This would have been SO MUCH QUICKER and easier if you'd posted a clear requirement in the original question.

Comment: one more requirement please.. what about BN , MN like figure is too long so want BN or MN or K keyword at the end

Comment: That's a different question - and I'm sure Google can help you.

Comment: ok if i did not found then i will post question .. thanku for cooperating and endurance me :)

Comment: please check this thread.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946522/expression-in-power-bi-and-qliksense