# Expression in power bi and qliksense

Tags: expression, powerbi-desktop, qliksense

I have 2 files one is in qliksense and other is in power bi .. both have same tables and relationships..

qliksense expression is

```
if([Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = 'USD',
sum({<[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR])*139.2,
sum({<[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR]))
```

and

power bi expression is

**UPDATED**

```
Total Sales Variable = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUMX ( 
        VALUES ( test_billing_doc_header[Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] ),
        IF ( 
            test_billing_doc_header[Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = "USD",
            139.2,
            1
        ) * SUM ( test_biilingg_doc_item[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR] )
    ),
    test_billing_doc_header[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZG2" && test_billing_doc_header[Billing Type_FKART] <> "ZL2"
)
```

now the problem is qliksense expression show value **26,599,175,877.32** 
and power bi shows **6,800,260,015,222,45**

and i want qliksense value in power bi ..

this is the link for power bi file .. https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8aazcb19zt50l5/test4.pbix?dl=0

and this is for qliksense 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jltgdls5rbintn4/test.qvf?dl=0

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Qliksense expression is correct but in table with [Fiscal_Year] field there is no data (calendar is not calculated in loading script). I've changed it to Invoice_year which is not missing and result is:
   [image]

```
if([Billing Doc. currency_WAERK] = 'USD',
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR])*139.2,
sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Billing Type_FKART] -={'ZG2','ZL2'}>}[Billing Sales Amount_NETWR]))
```

2. I see also that there are difference in data as currency in PowerBi is already converted and in QlikSense not. Please use straight tables and pivot tables to analyze your data so it will be easier for you:

Power BI table (without any conversions - just simple sum and filter to select Years and FKART):

[image: Power BI table]

QlikSense table (with set analysis and if result is the same as in Power Bi without currency conversion):
[image: Qliksense table]

Comment: no.. this is not working ? @Huberk Duek .. u just changed the varaible name ?

Comment: added ALL prefix

Comment: u means i just add the prefix "ALL" ?

Comment: I ADDED but this is not working .. .@Hubert Dudek .. will you eidt this power bi dax command

Comment: HEY... there is some problems in fiscal year.. so i remove that fiscal year from power bi and qlik sense file.. so now check still qlik sense has 26,599,175,877.32 value and i want that value in power bi .. kindly check update qlik sense and power bi files

Comment: will try to check it tomorrow

Comment: hey.. have you check it @Hubert Dudek

Comment: Hi I opened your files again and PowrBI is failing on relationships as there should be relation on %BKey 1 to 1 and it is not allowing. Please during load do just inner join on %BKey so you will have 1 table in PowerBI and no problems.